# How do you use Custom Objects in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have the same question as on [this page](http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-use-Custom-Objects-in-Xcode-4):

> In Interface Builder 3, we can drag custom object( ex. subview obj
>   UIView ) to the stage.  But in XCode 4, after we create a xib, I have
>   trouble to reuse it except by code.
>   And In the "Object Library" -> "Custom Objects",it's empty.
>
> [image: Custom Objects in Xcode 4]

But the answer given there doesn't work for me. I drag the xib file to Custom Objects list but it doesn't add anything to the list.

Comment: I'd like to edit your question to let it encompass OS X development, not just iPhone development (as @Michael points out), but I'd feel like I was changing the essence of the question, so I'll let you decide if you'd like to change the question.

Comment: I think instead of sucking hours with Interface Builder, you should simply create your view from code.

Answer (score 12):

Since you tagged this question as "iPhone" I am assuming you are doing iOS development. You cannot use the "Custom Objects" feature of Xcode for iOS development -- it is meant for use in apps developed for Mac.

The closest you can really get to mimicking this feature for iPhone development is to create your own custom UIView component which you can then drag between xib files.

You can also create a custom UIView subclass that has a .h/.m/.xib file. If you want to create your object programmatically, you can just do this:

```
NSArray *items = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyClass" owner:owner options:nil];
id myView = [items objectAtIndex:0];
```

With regards to Mac development, the Custom Objects panel isn't actually used anymore. I would imagine that this feature will either be left out of future versions of Xcode or that Apple is still working on improving support for IB plugins. Previous versions of Xcode and Interface Builder (back when IB was it's own app) had support for interface builder plugins and the creation of custom UI elements. [BWToolkit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/) is an example of one such plugin. From the documentation:

> Xcode 4 provides limited support for Interface Builder 3 plug-ins.
>   Specifically, you can build a project with Interface Builder plug-in
>   dependencies, but you can’t edit the nib files. When you try to open a
>   nib file with plug-in dependencies, Xcode 4 displays a dialog
>   suggesting that you update the file (Figure 4-3). If you agree, Xcode
>   converts the class of custom objects built with plug-ins to the
>   nearest AppKit class. If the conversion isn’t possible, Xcode 4
>   provides a detailed error message. In that case, you must remove the
>   plug-in dependency using Interface Builder 3 before you can edit the
>   nib file in Xcode 4.

Comment: This is very helpful, and it does answer the question considering that the question is in fact tagged as iPhone, but I'd really appreciate if you could add additional information on how this Custom Objects feature could be used in OS X development.

Comment: I added a note about Mac development.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer. You can't create custom objects past Xcode 3.x.

[How to use "Custom Objects" in IB in XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054826/how-to-use-custom-objects-in-ib-in-xcode-4)

If you open an Xcode 3 project with a Custom Object, it'll appear in this list.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an alternative way to do this.

1. Create a .nib file. do whatever you want to do in this .nib, such as an UIView with some UI controls.
2. Copy this custom UIView.
3. Back to the storyboard you want to add this custom UIView.
4. Select the target UIViewController and paste it, done.

Answer (score -6):

You can specify the custom class in the Interface builder
In the class drop down you can choose the custom class for the ui element in Interface builder. The class has to be added to the project inorder for it to appear in the drop down.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this approach works if the custom class has a xib as part of it, it only works when the custom class is only based on a .h and .m file

Comment: Definitely a difference between Custom Interface Builder Objects and Custom Class.