# How to use "Custom Objects" in IB in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

[image: Custom Objects]

This is in Xcode 4 and it leads me to believe that I can create, and reuse, custom objects. However, I can not find any method of doing so.

**How do you use this?** Does anyone know?

Comment: This is a really great question; I'd love to be able to implement this feature.

Comment: I've seen this question asked here and other forums and no one seems to understand if it is even possible. I've tried dragging all sorts of objects into it with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you currently can't use the Custom Objects section to create custom objects.

The Custom Objects section contains third-party Interface Builder elements. Older versions of Xcode and Interface Builder supported the creation of custom user interface elements. [BWToolkit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit) contains examples of custom elements. If you open an old Xcode project in Xcode 4 that contains custom elements, those elements appear in the Custom Objects section. Xcode 4 does not currently allow you to edit xib files that contain custom user interface elements, reducing the usefulness of the Custom Objects section.

If you would like to be able to create custom user interface elements in Xcode 4, [file a bug report with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter).

Comment: So in other words, if I create IBPlugin with an OLDER version of Xcode that I just happen to have lying around (funny that :) then I can use Custom Objects.

THIS is a clear answer. It explains a) you can't use it and b) why it exists.

I am sure others have attempted to answer this but instead ramble on about "Xcode 4 not having IBPlugins and how could they do this?!!" - instead of answering the question.

Thanks. That clears things up. I don't think I will bother writing a plugin for something that Apple clearly wants to deprecate.

Comment: Just a clarification: Apple's documentation says that you can't edit nibs created with IBPlugins - merely compile them. So I guess I'm still at a loss as why this panel exists. Just something that hasn't been removed?