# How to add a custom object to Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I want to create an object and use it on my project. I able to do it, but under the objects panel of xib file there is a pop up list that shows these values:

> Cocoa touch [Controls, Data Views, and ...]
>
> Custom objects

The Custom objects list is empty! Is any way to add my objects to this list? What is this list exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by adding an object. Do you want to create a new class? If so, choose Objective-C Class from the Cocoa Touch menu.

Comment: No, I saw a "custom objects" when I selected on "Objects" on right panel of one xib file, I want to know is any way to add an object that I was created before to this list?

Comment: @Fa.Shapouri Read the following question: [How to use “Custom Objects” in IB in XCode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054826/how-to-use-custom-objects-in-ib-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list is indeed meant to save custom object templates. You could create those custom objects and then pull them into the list for later reuse.

However, it doesn't seem to work in the current stable version (4.5.2) of Xcode.

You should check if it works in the latest developer preview. If it doesn't you should probably [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).